# When I run this code I got the error:"TypeError: argument must be a string or number"

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

Here is my code:

```
lbl_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y = lbl_enc.fit_transform(data.name_of_the_column.values)
```

The column "name_of_the_column" is str. How can I solve it?

```
IN : type(data.name_of_the_column.values[1])
OUT: str
```

Comment: What is `type(data.name_of_the_column.values)` ?

Comment: I want to show it is str

Comment: There are some "nan" value in this column,how to deal with them?

Comment: Hey, I solved it by drop the rows in ""name_of_the_column " whose value is "NAN":

Comment: Here is  my code:```data.dropna(subset = ["name_of_the_column"], inplace=True)```